# How can I change all the elements in a form to be disabled using only javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML:

```
     <div id="account-form">
        <form action="/Account/Login" id="login-form" class="form" method="post">
            <div id="input-fields">
                <div>
                    <input class="medium-margin" id="UserName" name="UserName">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="medium-margin" id="Password" name="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="medium glossy" id="login" type="submit">Login</button>
            <button class="medium glossy" id="register" type="button" onclick="location.href='/Account/Register'">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I am using the following to disable the buttons:

```
   document.getElementById("login").disabled = true;
   document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
```

What I would like is to disable the `<input>` and the `<button>` . Is there a way I could do this without getting each element by Id.

Comment: Just to put this out there - I usually give these elements a specific class or container so that I don't accidentally turn off other things on the page, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get elements using `getElementsByTagName` with return collection HTML elements

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].disabled  = true;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gqm2G/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".medium-margin").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

You can do it by class name

Answer (score 0):

Get the elements like this: `document.getElementsByTagName('input')` and `document.getElementsByTagName('button')`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="account-form">
        <form action="/Account/Login" id="login-form" class="form" method="post">
            <div id="input-fields">
                <div>
                    <input class="medium-margin" id="UserName" name="UserName">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input class="medium-margin" id="Password" name="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="medium glossy" id="login" type="submit" disabled>Login</button>
            <button class="medium glossy" id="register" type="button" onclick="location.href='/Account/Register'" disabled>Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

The above code works for you, i think. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$('input').attr('disabled',true);
```

or

```
$('button').attr('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

If You want to disable multiple buttons, You can use same method.

Using jQuery:

```
 $('input').each(function() {

                $(this).attr({
                    'disabled': 'disabled'
                });

        });
```